# ReactJS: checksum was invalid

Tags: reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I'm receiving this error, because server renders version of the webapp for not-authenticated users, which means some of UI elements are absent. Client side retrieves locally stored user token, then automatic authentication happens and client side renders slightly different DOM.  The logic is ok, right? But how do i make this error stop popping up?

```
React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server:
 (client) d=".c4gd6urcw.2.0"><noscript data-reacti
 (server) d=".c4gd6urcw.2.0"><div data-reactid=".c
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies to store the token so the server can read them and handle the authentication there. Or, if you're set on keeping it in LocalStorage, as long as you trigger a secondary render after the initial that handles the login it should satisfy React. The warning is that it has to rerender your entire app since the checksums don't match. Maybe something like this?

```
componentDidMount() {
  // this is only called client side after the server render
  if (localStorageHasToken) {
    handleAuth()
  }
}
```

The goal is just to make that initial client render match what the server sent it initially. Throwing the authentication in a new process should ensure the initial checksums match and then the rest is just basic React rerendering.